# How to install ruamel.yaml python library offline?

Tags: python, pip, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to install ruamel.yaml python library in a Centos 7 machine where I don't have internet connection. I tried this:

1. installed libyaml-devel, python-devel, python-pip using a local repository
2. downloaded ruamel.yaml-0.13.14.tar & ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.6.tar(dependency) from pypi.
3. now I am able to install ruamel.ordereddict using pip install .,
   but when I tried to install ruamel.yaml in the same way, I got the following exception:

   ```
   [root@limulus ruamel.yaml-0.13.14]# pip install .
   Processing /tmp/python/ruamel.yaml-0.13.14
   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
       from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
       from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
       from setuptools.command.install import install
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
       from setuptools.command import install_scripts
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
       from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 74, in <module>
       import parser
     File "parser.py", line 77, in <module>
       from ruamel.yaml.error import MarkedYAMLError                  # type: ignore
     File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ruamel/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
       __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'declare_namespace'

   ----------------------------------------
   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-oOWX1x-build/
   ```

What is the correct way of installing a python library in offline mode?

Comment: What does the following print on command line? python -c "print __import__('pkg_resources').__file\_\_"

Comment: @Bemmu It is giving **AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'declare_namespace'** error.

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2679

Comment: That sounds surprising. So if you go to interactive Python and type in "import pkg_resources" that results in an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have been expanding the tar files, which is not necessary, but I am not sure if that is the reason why you get this error, you probably are also missing the `typing` dependency.

What you shouldn't do is use the system installed `pip`, it is almost out of date and on some systems actually causes problems because of unfixed bugs in those old versions.

What you also should not do is install packages using `pip` outside of a Python virtualenv, as this might break your system when it updates/overwrites things in the systems `site-packages/dist-packages` directory. The solution provided below only installs pip/wheels/virtualenv in the system directory, that is AFAIK safe, but there are ways around that as well if it would necessary.

You should also consider using the provided wheels to install packages. That way C extension don't need compilation.

On a machine that is online do:

```
mkdir /tmp/offline
cd /tmp/offline
# your python-pip installed pip might not support wheels
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/11/b6/abcb525026a4be042b486df43905d6893fb04f05aac21c32c638e939e447/pip-9.0.1.tar.gz
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/a7/37/947b4329c4a3c72093b6c8e9b4be8c7f10c32dbb78848d3a234ce01c059d/wheel-0.30.0a0.tar.gz
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/6f/86/3dc328ee7b1a6419ebfac7896d882fba83c48e3561d22ddddf38294d3e83/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Now download the required wheels (.tar.gz if not available):

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/96/4b/5251bf469f37e49e0c92f841b5b3ef01a1c9d652cc018df470e5ae235eb8/ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.9-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/63/40/c38b857ec6a083e534ee9a9f655741120d4bfd9139232681f976cf44272b/ruamel.yaml-0.13.14-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/b6/0c/53c42edca789378b8c05a5496e689f44e5dd82bc6861d1ae5a926ee51b84/typing-3.5.3.0.tar.gz
```

Copy the six files to a new directory your offline system, and there do

```
sudo pip install pip*.tar.gz wheel*.tar.gz
sudo pip install virtualenv*
virtualenv ~/ruamel
source ~/ruamel/bin/activate
pip install typing* ruamel*
```

That gives you a virtualenv with `ruamel.yaml` installed, just add your application in there as well.

The downloads used here are current as of 2017-01-07, you can get more up-to-date ones using your browser (on the on-line system) if necessary.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I followed the steps that you mentioned, in the last step I got                                                                               `(ruamel) [abhishek@limulus ruamel]$ pip install typing* ruamel*               
 ruamel.ordereddict-0.4.9-cp26-cp26mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: my linux version:                                                                    `[abhishek@limulus ruamel]$ uname -a
Linux limulus.example.com 3.10.0-327.36.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 18 13:04:29 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: I made a mistake in copying and pasting, you need the ruamel.ordereddict wheel for 2.7 not the one for Python 2.6, sorry

Comment: yes, I downloaded the correct .whl file(for python 2.7) and it worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.